# How do I change acceptance with decimal separator to . instead of , with input in Netbeans IDE 7.0.1 on Windows 7 x 64 english?

Tags: java, netbeans, input, decimal

How do I change acceptance with decimal separator to . instead of , with input in Netbeans IDE 7.0.1?

This is within Netbeans itself like trying this -->

```
System.out.println("Cost?: ");
cost = keyboard.nextDouble();
```

If this is input with 37.5 following happens -->

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:840)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1461)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2387)
    at Lab3_ChangeMoney.main(CostProgram.java:47)
Java Result: 1
```

But with input 37,5 its ok

I tried via Control Panel, but not

Comment: You haven't given *nearly* enough context here. Is this in your code, or in NetBeans itself? What are you trying to do, and what does your code look like? Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> An instance of this class is capable of scanning numbers in the standard formats as well as in the formats of the scanner's locale. A scanner's initial locale is the value returned by the `Locale.getDefault()` method; it may be changed via the `useLocale(java.util.Locale)` method.

So this could be fixed by setting the locale to [`Locale.US`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html):

```
keyboard.useLocale(Locale.US);
```

Read more about localized numbers on [the manual](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#localized-numbers)